# React Navigation: how to detect if a screen is inside a TabNavigator or a DrawerNavigator?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm creating a demo app and requirement is that on ios app must use tabs, and on Android must use drawer.

No problem, I created both configuration and applied live, and added to each screens both drawer-related and tabs-related configs.

I need to hide navbar icon which opens the drawer if screen is inside a tabnavigator, and show only if is inside a drawer navigator

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution

Please, post your answers, if found a better way

```
export default class Contacts extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

    return {
      title: 'Contacts',
      headerLeft: navigation.actions.toggleDrawer
        ? (<MaterialIcons name="menu" size={24}
          style={{ color: colors.grey, marginLeft: 10 }}
          onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
        />)
        : null,
    };
  }

  ... rest of component code ..
```